# Slick slider not playing the current slide video

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have 3 mp4 videos in slick slider. I need the functionality that when we move to next slide. the video in the previous slide should be paused. for that I'm pausing all the videos once we move into next slide which is working fine.
**Now I need to autoplay the video in the current slide.**

**HTML Code**

```
 <div id="slick" dir="ltr" class="hero-slider">

    <div class="respsonsive-video " > <video autoplay muted loop id="video" class="" controls 
    preload="none" width="100%" height="100%"> <source src="t1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> </video>  </div> 

    <div class="respsonsive-video " > <video autoplay muted loop id="video" class="" controls 
    preload="none" width="100%" height="100%"> <source src="t1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> </video>  </div> 

    <div class="respsonsive-video " > <video autoplay muted loop id="video" class="" controls 
    preload="none" width="100%" height="100%"> <source src="t1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> </video>  </div> 
</div>
```

Js
Here is the code for the slider and two functionality for play and pause.
Pause is working 100% but playing the video again in current slide is not working.

```
   $(window).load(function () {
       
    
    $('.hero-slider').slick({
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed:3500,
        arrows:true,
        prevArrow:'<button type="button" class="slick-prev"></button>',
        nextArrow:'<button type="button" class="slick-next"></button>',
        //centerMode:true,
        slidesToShow:1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 960,
            settings: {
                autoplay: false,
                //autoplaySpeed: 3500,
                arrows: true,
                prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"></button>',
                nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"></button>',
                //centerMode:true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                arrows: false,
                dots: true,

            }
        }],


    onInit: function() {
      $('span.css-loader').hide();
      $('.slide').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('data-bgcolor'));
      });
      $('.next-slide').on('click', function() {
          $('.hero-slider').slickNext();
          
      });
      $('.prev-slide').on('click', function() {
          $('.hero-slider').slickPrev();
        
      });

    
    }
    });
    });
  
// On slide change, pause all videos
$('.hero-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  $('video').each(function() {
    $(this).get(0).pause();
  });
});



**// On slide chnage, play a video inside the current slide
$('.hero-slider').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    if ($('.hero-slider.slick-current').find('video').length !== 0) {
        $(".hero-slider .slick-current video")[0].play();
       
  }
    });**


});
```

Comment: Please add demo in jsfiddle.